# Printing from an Altium / CircuitStudio PDF 3D page - with desired camera view?

Tags: pdf, printing, 3d

So, I've gotten some PDF made with Altium / CircuitStudio, which contain a 3D rendering of a PCB.

I'd like to export this 3D view as a 2D image - and since there is no direct option to do so, what I tried to do is to "print" the 3D PDF page from Adobe Acrobat Reader as a PDF, using a "print to PDF" driver.

Unfortunately, that does not quite work: if you set up a camera view in the 3D model, like this:

[image: 3d view 01 adobe reader]

... and then I select Print (either to "Microsoft Print to PDF", or to "PDF Architect 9"), then the export process starts, and output "printed" PDF does get generated, unfortunately NOT with the camera view that I've set up previously; usually after the print process is over and I come back to Adobe Acrobat Reader 3D page, the camera view has changed:

[image: 3d view 02 adobe reader]

... and it is usually THIS view that gets exported in the output PDF, not the one I set up!

Is there any way to print/export an image of this kind of a 3D model *with the camera view that **I** choose*?

Comment: The 'dumb' way to do this might be to take a screenshot and print the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks @JourneymanGeek - unfortunately I work on a somewhat small screen, and I cannot increase the Adobe Reader in size enough, so I get a decent resolution for "printout", which is why I wanted to go the "virtual PDF printer" route, there at least I can do "fit" and choose a large page size.

Comment: Also - I'm guessing from the pixelation that the actual circuit board is private but an 'example' PDF for testing might be useful

Comment: Thanks @JourneymanGeek - I'd would have loved to oblige, unfortunately I do not own the original software, I received the PDF from a third party (and I do not even know if they really do use Altium, I just saw CircuitStudio in the PDF metadata and looked it up).. Anyways, it seems 3D viewers in PDF are up to the publisher, since I tried https://www.pdf3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Panoramic-Sheldonian-Theater-PDF3D.pdf and that one prints correctly whatever camera view you set, so this could be Altium CircuitMaker specific.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with CircuitStudio (I use Altium Designer) but do you have an outjob file that exports the files? I'm sure there was a image export option in there, again at least in Designer I'm sure there is. Will check in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

In Altium Designer there actually is a direct option to get that 3D image, hopefully you'll have it too in Circuit Studio.

In PCB view get the angle you want, and then instead of exporting a "PDF3D", do a "PCB 3D Print". That will open a window where you will be able to do exactly what you [want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp6gm.png).